# Allowing Multiple Accounts from the Same E-Mail Address WEB API ASP.NET IDENTITY

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, identity

I want to create multiple users using asp.net identity framework **with same email addresses and different usernames**.

Is it possible?

When I try to create users with same email address i get this error

```
{
  "message": "The request is invalid.",
  "modelState": {
    "": [
      "Email 'tester123@live.com' is already taken."
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can configure `UserValidator` of `UserManager`: `RequireUniqueEmail = false`

Comment: Thank You. You saved my time. I have override UserManager class and boom. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not add begging to your posts. I have edited this once already, and now that you've rolled back, I'll be asking a moderator to take a look at it. [Read this community discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure `UserValidator` of `UserManager`: `RequireUniqueEmail = false`. Example code for default MVC5 with Individual User Accounts:

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

    // Configure validation logic for usernames
    manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = false 
    };

    ...

    return manager;
}
```

You might need to set it in `ApplicationUserManager` class constructor:

```
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store) : base(store)
{
    UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = true
    };
 }
```